# What gradle task is invoked when android studio build variant changes?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, gradle

I'm trying to configure kotlin in my project, and I've found that my kotlin functions are mangled when they have visibility scope of `internal`. Having names mangled are all fine except that the mangled names include build variants. So in my Java code I have to write `kotlinFunction$module_debug` or `kotlinFunction$module_release`.

The problem is, when I switch the build variant, the suffix should be changed too. For example, I was coding in build variant debug, so I wrote `kotlinFunction$module_debug`, and then when I switch to build variant release, all my method references break and I have to change all kotlin references to `kotlinFunction$module_release`. This is OK, we can automate this easily, so I wrote a simple script to do this.

However, the problem I face now is that **I do not know when to trigger this script**. I assume build variant change triggers some gradle action, but my below code did not work.

```
task javaUnMangle(type: Exec) {
    def variants = ["debug", "release", "local_ci"]
    for (String variant in variants) {
        if (gradle.startParameter.taskRequests.any {it.args.any {it.toLowerCase().contains(variant.toString())}}) {
            commandLine "python3", "java_kotlin_internal_call_flavor_changer.py", variant
            return
        }
    }
}

project.afterEvaluate {
    preBuild.dependsOn javaUnMangle
}
```

any tips or feedbacks are appreciated.

Note: Making all functions `public` is not an option for us as we develop libraries. Thank you.